# Adding class="active" to jcarousellite slides

Tags: jquery, jcarousellite

I am in need of a way to add an active class to JCarouselLite. What I want to do is set an opacity of .5 to all slides, except the active slide which will be 100% opacity. When the next button is clicked and the carousel slides, I want to remove the active class from the slide and add it to the next slide. Does anyone have experience with this or know of a slider that already implements this feature? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
$(".slide.active").removeClass("active").next(".slide").addClass("active");
```

If chaining that way doesn't work, this will for sure:

```
var activeSlide = $(".slide.active");
activeSlide.removeClass("active");
activeSlide.next(".slide").addClass("active");
```

Your styles would probably look something like this:

```
.slide
{
    opacity: .5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}
.slide.active
{
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
}
```